How to solve connect failed error, connection failed
I am using Mail Reader Sampler to read an email from the google mail and I am getting the error like connect failed. I have tried and read about the articles available in internet but no use. How can I resolve this issue?




You should use pop3s protocol
You should use port 995
You might also need to set mail.pop3s.ssl.protocols=TLSv1.2 JMeter System Property

